# Way to utilize iCloud shared album externally

Tags: icloud, photos, sharing

I use iCloud to share photos with people, and I would like to use that resources in my personal blogs(similar to AWS S3)

I know there is a way to access the shared photos via web, but is there any way to access it more convenient?

Comment: It would be helpful if you clarified "externally" and "more convenient" than accessing the photos via web.

Answer (score 1):

You can make albums, share links and make the albums public **on macOS**.

**On iOS:**
Create a "New Shared Album" and turn on "Public Website" in People's tab in the album itself, not the global one.

> You can even share albums with friends and family who don't use iCloud. Just open a Shared Album that you created, go to the People tab on your iOS device or click the people icon on your Mac, and turn on Public Website. Your photos publish to a website that anyone can see in an up-to-date web browser.

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202786